# How to specify header search path when using R CMD SHLIB to compile a C++ file?

Tags: c++, r, boost

I'm trying to compile a C++ file which uses the Boost library on Mac OSX. For example, see the following "simple.cpp"

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>
using namesapce boost::math;

int main(){
    boost::mt19937 rng;
    rng.seed(static_cast<boost::uint32_t> (std::time(0)));

    return 0;
}
```

If I compile the file in the command shell with

```
g++ -I/usr/local/boost simple.cpp
```

then everything is fine. But I'd like to build a shared library so that I can use it to speed up my R project. If I use

```
R CMD SHLIB test.cpp
```

then it reports the header file can not be found. Is there a way to specify the search path for R CMD? Something like

```
R CMD SHLIB -I/usr/local/boost test.cpp
```

Comment: There's an example in `?SHLIB`.

Comment: (1) There probably should not be a space between the `<` and `boost/random.hpp` in the `#include` line.  (2) If you needed to specify `-I/usr/local/boost` on the G++ command line (so the header was installed as `/usr/local/boost/boost/random.hpp`), then you'd probably need to do the same for the R command.  Alternatively, G++ may look in `/usr/local/include` automatically (and then finds the file `/usr/local/include/boost/random.hpp`), but again, the R command doesn't do that (so you need to find out how to make it do so).

Comment: 'How to make it do so' is to set the standard Make variables which R respects as in my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to set `PKG_CXXFLAGS` -- see [the fine manual's Section 1.2. "Using Makevars"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) as well as
[Section 5.5 "Creating shared objects"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Creating-shared-objects) for details.

Comment: Glad to hear that. It is then customary to a) accept an answer (click on the "tickmark") and also to upvote it (click on the up-arrow).